# Using "definitely" with "may" or "might"

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm a little bit worried about the use of "**definitely**" with "**may**" or "**might**":

1. I may definitely come to you in the evening.
2. He might definitely steal it from the shop if we don't stop him.

Could such a combination be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are pretty much oxymorons, although *definitely* might be considered an intensifier if it is placed first:

> He definitely might steal it from the shop if we don't stop him.

i.e. I am sure that he might steal it (but I don't know if he will).

A well-known example of its use as an oxymoron (jokingly) is the phrase "definite maybe":

> "Are you coming to the disco tonight?"
>   "I dunno."
>   "That's a definite maybe, then?"

---

> **definite maybe** noun [ C ] informal
>   ​
>   something that you think you might do, but are not certain about:
>
> "Are you going to Helen's party?" "It's a definite maybe."

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/definite-maybe)